# using enum or other datatype for 3 repetitive values

Tags: mysql

I am creating a dashboard to display information from a mysql database. The information being displayed primarily deals with tracking information. I have a script that is first pulling in information, making a decision as to what the data is and then storing it in a table. One of the columns in the table refers to the shipping company (UPS, FedEx, USPS). Is it more efficient to use ENUM to represent the value of 1 of the 3 shipping companies, or is there a more efficient way of storing these repeated values?

Comment: [Of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824718/4807879).

Comment: [Also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295889/4807879).

Comment: [_This_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693283/data-model-having-separate-table-for-a-field-vs-having-it-as-a-column-in-the-ma/51940188#51940188) is aimed at MySQL/MariaDB